# How to make a column independent of next rows?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Let's suppose that i have a first row with 2 columns, the first one with a width of 10  columns (col-md-10) and the second one with a width of 2 columns (col-md-2).

What i want to do is to make the second column independent of the rows coming after so that it can have a long column near to all the rows of the page. It's a kind of right sidebar.

Here is a picture to show you what i want to do:
[image]

Can anyone help me on this please ?

Edit: If there is w way to make a fixed right sidebar, i can take that solution :)

Comment: Do you have any HTML or CSS already? Maybe adding a jsFiddle would encourage people to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/126716)

And here is some code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <h1>Left Stuff</h1>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <h1>Right stuff</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think this is what you meant.